# How does the community feel about removing some community wikis?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

We have a lot of [answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aanswer) and [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion) which for various reasons became community wiki over the years (variety of reasons).

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257253/193412):

> ### Guidelines for un-Wikiing
>
> And that's still the case: generally-speaking, moderators will
> cheerfully remove CW status on posts as long as...
>
> 1. They *don't* appear to be actual community projects (lots of substantive edits from multiple editors maintaining the post over
>    time).
> 2. They're *not* part of some old discussion / poll / GTKY question that was only allowed under the old rules for squishy-subjective
>    posts.
> 3. You *weren't* clearly abusing the system by making dozens of worthless edits merely to bump the thread.
>
> ...In other words, those cases where the system clearly *got it wrong*
> and converted the post to CW unnecessarily. Which... Is a lot of them.

Are there questions/answers from there people feel should be unwikied or are unfairly wiki'ied?

Note: it's probably easiest and best to use answers for this to vote on/etc.

Comment: Please use answers to make proposals, so it's easier for people to express agreement or disagreement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On a general note - per my reading, unwikiing as described in quoted guidance suggests rather strong moderator effort and scrutiny of the questions and answers.

Because of this, it looks reasonable to complement unwiki review with "Atwood's cleanup", following [guidance provided in related discussion at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773):

> ...answers that are strong candidates for deletion:
>
> - belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community
> - are *provably* duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information
> - are short in length
> - do not explain much of anything

Now, few observations related to some specific wiki posts...

---

This question looks... inconsistent regarding wiki status:

- [How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus)

Wiki is removed from above question, but kept for its answers. We had meta discussion on it, but it appears to be hanging without understandable resolution: [Un-community wiki this question?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/un-community-wiki-this-question)

---

Below two questions look like "wrong kind of wiki" - as far as I can tell, [collaborative effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/165773) lock is more appropriate:

- [What should I know when applying for my first job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/what-should-i-know-when-applying-for-my-first-job)
- [Should an employee tell their supervisor about their depression?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/should-an-employee-tell-their-supervisor-about-their-depression)

---

Checking revisions history of below question, I can't make up my mind whether it qualifies for "worthless edits merely to bump" or not. If edits are indeed reasonable, then I think it would be better to un-wiki it:

- [What to do with the new boss -- middle manager added to hierarchy?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/what-to-do-with-the-new-boss-middle-manager-added-to-hierarchy)

---

Per my reading, following questions look worthy of close and [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info) instead of unwikiing:

- [How should I deal with an employee who has slept with my wife?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/how-should-i-deal-with-an-employee-who-has-slept-with-my-wife)
  Appears to fall under ["asking for advice on what to do"](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168)
- [What is a 'friendly' way to let managers know that having good developers is a privilege?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/what-is-a-friendly-way-to-let-managers-know-that-having-good-developers-is-a-p)
  Appears to fall under ["focus on how terrible a situation is"](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/168)

Historical lock suggested because these questions have over 50K views each.

---

I also briefly checked other [open wiki questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+locked%3Ano).

Per cursory glance, all of them look worth considering for unwikiing. Just please keep in mind that I did not check their revisions history for either "substantive edits from multiple editors" or "worthless edits" that could probably qualify for keeping them CW.