# Why was this question automatically made into a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

## [How do you explain to your boss they're wrong without making them feel threatened?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/how-do-you-explain-to-your-boss-theyre-wrong-without-making-them-feel-threatene)

This is a pretty old question, dating back to June 2013. It got a lot of traction and is now up to 15 answers. But the weird thing I'm seeing is that it was converted into a Community Wiki question two days after being posted, as seen in the [Revision history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/12173/revisions).

This conversion was presumably automatic because it says it was done by a new user who posted an answer on the question at the same time (18:48).

But I'm wondering why this conversion triggered. As I understand it, none of the conditions for automatic wiki were met (30 answers, 10+ edits on a single post)?

I *think* it may be due to a lower CW limit for smaller sites. [This comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/#comment_19) on a blog post mention a 15 answer trigger for SuperUser, but I can't find any sources to back this up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we reduce the Community Wiki threshold to 10 answers?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/280/should-we-reduce-the-community-wiki-threshold-to-10-answers)

Comment: CW threshold was set to 15 answers since Jan 2013

Comment: @gnat [Checks out](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1659/25739). The main "What are CWs" meta thread didn't mention any other sites except for SU [back in 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/23). Add an answer if you'd like, otherwise I'll probably add it in for completion's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back when automatic conversion to community wiki was a thing, the threshold on The Workplace was [set to 15](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/325) rather than the 30 seen on much of the rest of the network.  See the discussion there for the background.