# Reasoning for answer deletion?

Tags: discussion

My answer to a question was deleted [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/is-it-my-responsibility-to-inform-hr-of-illegal-events-performed-by-coworkers-th/14687#14687).

The reasoning for deletion is:
Help Center > Answering

> Why and how are some answers deleted?
>
> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> commentary on the question or other answers
> asking another, different question
> “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> exact duplicates of other answers
> barely more than a link to an external site
> not even a partial answer to the actual question

None of those reasons are relevant.  It is a short answer that fulfills answering the question and does not need to be expanded upon.  So why was it deleted when it was receiving upvotes?

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't a good answer.

---

Imagine I stopped writing anything after the above line, so my answer to your question here was simply "It wasn't a good answer." Would you feel as if I answered your question well? What I said would definitely be *true* and probably get some upvotes but it would be a really low quality answer to your question.

See this text which is currently on the answer:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Here's [my thoughts](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/we-need-to-downvote-answers-more-even-mediocre-ones) on the matter in a generic sense.

Your answer was:

> You should mind your business. Let HR and the hiring managers worry about properly conducting background checks.

I personally downvoted but did not vote to delete. This is a comment at best because you don't explain:

- Why should the OP "mind your own business?" Obviously the asker is curious about this. Saying basically "no" to a more complicated question is difficult
- Let's say the situation was "I murdered coworkers at my last company." Nothing in your answer indicates the situation would be any different.

Comment: As the final delete voter, this is exactly why I voted to delete it. The answer didn't even attempt to explain the logic and didn't follow the 'back it up' principle.

Answer (score 3):

The Workplace SE is a very subjective topic, one where it's difficult to identify exactly who the experts are.  As a result, our community has decided to apply the fundamentals from The Six Guidelines for a Good Subjective Question from [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

The first two of the six guidelines focus on how answers should explain *why* and *how* and should be longer instead of shorter. It reads as follows:

> **1. Great subjective questions inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.** The best subjective questions invite explanation. If you’re asking for a product recommendation of some kind, you want answers to contain detailed information about the features and how they can be used, and why you might want to choose one over the other. “How?” and “Why?” has more lasting value than a bunch of product-feature bullet points or a giant enumerated list, no matter how extensive. In contrast, the bad subjective questions let answerers get away with hit-and-run answers that maybe provide a name and a link — but fail to provide any sort of adequate explanation, context, or background.
>
> **2. Great subjective questions tend to have long, not short, answers.** The best subjective questions inspire your peers to share their actual experiences, not just post a mindless one-liner or cartoon in hopes of being rewarded with upvotes for being merely “first.” Sharing an experience takes at least one paragraph; ideally several paragraphs. If I’m asking about how to bake cookies, don’t give me a list of grocery items: milk. butter. vanilla. eggs. There is virtually nothing I can learn from a short, static list of grocery items that make up a recipe. Instead, tell me what happened the last time you made cookies from that recipe! Share your detailed experiences, so that we all might learn from them.

We've also adopted a version of the "Back It Up Principle", based on the early experiment with Moms4Moms:

> The folks at Moms4mom owned up to the subjective issue and came up with a set of principles to create useful subjective discussions on parenting: the Back It Up! Principle. Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either:
>
> - Something that happened to you **personally**
> - Something you can **back up** with a reference
>
> They talk about how “opinion, by itself, is noise.” They’re not saying that subjective opinions are to be avoided; they’re attempting to mold and shape their inherently subjective Q&A into something constructive, informative and helpful. As it turns out, there is an entire field of subjective “expertise” that has the hallmarks of making **great Q&A sites**

It's clear you feel passionate about your answer, so you could edit and expand upon your answer to [back it up](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others) and explain why a person shouldn't get involved in being a whistleblower.  When you do, feel free to flag it and we'll take a look at undeleting it.

Hope this helps!