# Is a question opinion-based if all answers are of the same opinion?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, opinion-based

I noticed [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17334/9549) has been put on hold. I normally wouldn't look twice and trust the 'hive mind' SE operates on but this time it struck me as a bit odd.

To quote the relevant parts:

> My previous job title was 'Senior development engineer' [...] Compared to a programmer in a large corporate, software house I am probably equivalent to a mid level programmer [...] [Recruiters] associate this word with being in charge of a team of software developers.

and goes on

> Do you think it would be wise to change my title to something like 'Software Engineer' to remove the confusion?

The question has been put on hold as primarily opinion-based. So far so good, but let's take a look at the answers:

[Ross Dew's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17348/9549):

> I think you are under valuating yourself. [...] Just make it clear at interviews that you were senior more with a bias towards project design and direction rather than people organization and I'm sure you'll be fine.

[jmoreno's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17345/9549):

> Tell the truth, use your actual title. The value and meanings of titles are company specific. [...] If you are working with a recruiter and are afraid that he will be looking for the wrong jobs for you, then have a discussion with him

[HLGEM's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17340/9549):

> Always put in your exact title, it is something easily checked in a reference chek and can look bad if you changed it. [...] Discuss with the recruiters that you are looking for mid-level positions not senior ones, [...] I am more comncerened with acual accomplishments than titles when I hire.

and [my own](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17335/9549):

> I don't think you need to. Senior sounds nice. [...] You are not responsible for what a recruiter assumes your previous role entailed, only for what you say it did.

---

All the answers say the same thing, each for different reasons. Of course there's [good subjective and bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) but this site makes it a point to include bits of personal experience - which (arguably) might make it a bit more subjective than others.

My question is this: If an otherwise well-formed question gets closed as opinion-based, but attracts answers of the same opinion (which suggests consensus therefore not individual opinion), should the question be re-opened?

For the reasons above I'd like to see the question re-opened, but I'd also like some discussion on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

> Is a question opinion-based if all answers are of the same opinion?
>   ...
>
> If an otherwise well-formed question gets closed as opinion-based, but
>   attracts answers of the same opinion (which suggests consensus
>   therefore not individual opinion), should the question be re-opened?

Not to get too Zen here, but for me, a question is judged on it's own merits, not on the answers it draws.

The same question either is or isn't opinion-based when it has no answers, one answer, many answers all with the same opinion, many answers with differing opinions.

In the case at hand, if the question has been closed as "opinion based" at the instant when it happens to have only a single opinion expressed in all the answer, then re-opened, what happens if it then attracts answers with differing opinions? Is it closed again? Seems odd to me.

Judge questions how ye may, but don't depend on the current answers to guide you.

Comment: Fair enough [+1]

Answer (score 3):

This question literally is asking (emphasis mine):

> **Do you think it would be wise** to change my title to something like
>   'Software Engineer' to remove the confusion or **is this a bad idea** as
>   it undermines my previous level of responsibility?.

It is the definition of the type of question we should avoid that asks for opinion.

That said I suspect that this question could be saved with a few edits to ask this constructively in a way that would not change the basics of the question or invalidate any of the answers.

Perhaps, "Is it acceptable to prospective employers if I alter a title on my resume to reflect the duties performed rather than the title assigned by the company?  Are their risks to doing this?"

I think that question would pass the good subjective test in my book.

Comment: I completely skipped over that part. I guess we see what we wanna see? [+1]

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to formulate an answer to this question that abides by the [Back It Up! Principle](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/we-need-to-downvote-answers-more-even-mediocre-ones/1894#1894).

Therefore, I voted to close.