# Restrict down-voting from people who answered

Tags: feature-request

*This is a feature request. A proper answer should be provided by the webmasters or so. Any opinion in regards with this feature request is just an opinion, be it pro or against, but not an answer. Also, maybe the answers from [this question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/are-the-downvoting-police-too-active) may reflect the webmaster's vision, but the questions are different, so this feature-request is not a duplicate question. Thank you.*

I've seen someone who answered a question down-voting my answer and the next answer of another member was also immediately down-voted and I suspected that someone is trying to influence the OP's "Best answer" mark by down-voting everybody's else answers.
Since the down-voter didn't provide any explanation I demanded one and the response was pure subjective and personal.

Therefore, I think it will be a good idea that the people who answered a question shouldn't be able to down-vote other answers. Also, if they down-vote someone and then post an answer that their down-votes should be ignored (with a notice, eventually).
In this way abuses would be avoided and the general idea behind the site will not be affected because there are enough readers to express their disagreement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the Downvoting police too active?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/are-the-downvoting-police-too-active)

Comment: @Joe Strazzere: The tag says "Feature request"

Comment: At first I didn't find questions on the same theme. Even if the "dupe" is a question and my post is a feature request, I found answers there quite usefull and even fun. This one got Nr.1 in my Top favourites: "come to The Workplace, get a downvote" :))

Comment: @TinelBarb - right. But your question indicates that you demanded an explanation: "Since the down-voter didn't provide any explanation I demanded one"

Comment: Looks like we may need to restrict down voting on questions about down voting.

Answer (score 7):

As one of the downvoters (and, admittedly, the first) I'd like to weigh in on this, as I get the feeling that this question comes from a general frustration as to how your answer was received. First of all, I'd like to say that I'm not completely heartless and I do understand your frustration. I've been downvoted before and I know it can *sting*. However, sometimes it's good to take a step back and think about whether or not you can do something to stop it happening again.

As I mentioned in my comment, I actually feel like your answer was on the right track and I didn't actually disagree with it. I just felt that you could have elaborated on your points more rather than listing them off. As it stood, your answer read more as a "Have you tried this?" than an authoritative answer to the question.

These points are, as you've highlighted, entirely subjective - this is why we vote as a community (and why, I suspect, the rep gain of an upvote outweighs a downvote 5:1). In theory, the community consensus will overrule those who vote for incorrect reasons.

To answer your specific question about people downvoting competing answers, this has been discussed quite extensively on the main SE meta:

[The answer to tactical downvoting problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem)

[Is it good practice to refrain from downvoting competing answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129304/is-it-good-practice-to-refrain-from-downvoting-competing-answers)

The problem with putting systems in place to prevent tactical voting is that it undermines a vital aspect of SO - that finding the best answer is king. Graeme Perrow sums it up perfectly in his answer in the first link:

> If I see an answer to a question that is just plain wrong, I should be able to both downvote it and post my own answer. This is such a fundamental part of SO that it's too heavy-handed to prevent it just to avoid a relatively minor problem.

The system already has measures in place to discourage it (badges for upvoting competing answers, rep loss for downvotes), but anything further would simply get in the way of the ultimate goal: finding the best answer.

Finally, I noticed that you took the time to go back to your post and make a big edit to it. This is really commendable behaviour and I'm happy to say that I've removed my downvote!